# iCal not correct time with google calender

Tags: outlook, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have a problem with my ical file.
In outlook I get the correct date `10.12.2015 20:00 - 10.12.2015 22:00`.

In my Google calendar I got the date `10.12.2015 20:00 - 23.00`.

The following is my ical file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:*****
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:*****
ORGANIZER;CN="admin":MAILTO:*****
LOCATION:*****
SUMMARY:*****
DESCRIPTION:
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20151210T200800
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20151210T220800
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: A small problem with your event is that it's not ending at 22:00, but 22:08. That should not cause the '1 horu off' problem though. I don't see anything inherently wrong with the event... is it possible that this is a google calendar bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DURATION property instead of DTEND.

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20151210T200800
DURATION:PT2H
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but this is not an option, because the user can change the enddate and not a duration.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like both clients are somehow rounding the time of the event from 20h08 / 22h08 to full hours. Given that the event runs after 22h, it makes as much sense to round it to 23h00: you probably don't want the user to doublebook the calendar by adding another event at 22h00, thinking that that slot is free when it is not (but that is no longer visible to the user).